# как сделать картинки посередине в @media ? Помогите пожалуйста

Tags: grid

Как сделать картинки посередине в @media (max-width: 600px) ? Помогите пожалуйста

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.ss {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3);
}



.cardd>a>img {
  width: 100%;
  }

  .cardd>.info {
    text-align: center;
  }


  @media (max-width: 1000px) {
   
.ss {
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(5);
}

} 
     /* ↓Тут↓ */
  @media (max-width: 600px) {
    .ss {
      grid-template-columns: repeat(1, 1fr);
      grid-template-rows: repeat(9)
    }
    
  }
```

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="static/styles/maincont.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="static/styles/cardcont.css">
  
</head>
<body>
  <div class="main-container">

    <div class="left-bar">
      
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quos, sint?</p>
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Asperiores incidunt corrupti quos recusandae optio sunt atque ab reiciendis obcaecati saepe. Vel sunt iusto rerum quibusdam.</p>
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quos, sint?</p>
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Asperiores incidunt corrupti quos recusandae optio sunt atque ab reiciendis obcaecati saepe. Vel sunt iusto rerum quibusdam.</p>
  
  </div>
    
    <div class="ss">
  
      <div class="cardd">
            <a href="#">
              <img class src="https://images.newscientist.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/19163900/credit_irina-dmitrienko-_-alamy.jpg?crop=16:9,smart&width=1200&height=675&upscale=true" alt="za dengi da">
            </a>
          <div class="info">
            <a href="#">
              <p>Space</p>
            </a>
           
            <button>Visit Now</button>
          </div>
  
      </div>
       <div class="cardd">
            <a href="#"><img src="https://images.newscientist.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/19163900/credit_irina-dmitrienko-_-alamy.jpg?crop=16:9,smart&width=1200&height=675&upscale=true" class="imagine-center" alt="za dengi da"></a>
          <div class="info">
            <a href="#">
              <p>Space</p>
            </a>
            
            <button>Visit Now</button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="cardd">
             <a href="#"><img src="https://images.newscientist.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/19163900/credit_irina-dmitrienko-_-alamy.jpg?crop=16:9,smart&width=1200&height=675&upscale=true" alt="za dengi da"></a>
           <div class="info">
             <a href="#">
               <p>Space</p>
             </a>
            
             <button>Visit Now</button>
           </div>
   
  
      </div>
       <div class="cardd">
            <a href="#"><img src="https://images.newscientist.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/19163900/credit_irina-dmitrienko-_-alamy.jpg?crop=16:9,smart&width=1200&height=675&upscale=true" alt="za dengi da"></a>
          <div class="info">
            <a href="#">
              <p>Space</p>
            </a>
            
            <button>Visit Now</button>
          </div>
  
      </div>
       <div class="cardd">
            <a href="#"><img src="https://images.newscientist.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/19163900/credit_irina-dmitrienko-_-alamy.jpg?crop=16:9,smart&width=1200&height=675&upscale=true" alt="za dengi da"></a>
          <div class="info">
           
            <A href="#">
              <p>Visit Now</p>
            </a>
            <button>Visit Now</button>
          </div>
  
      </div>
       <div class="cardd">
            <a href="#"><img src="https://images.newscientist.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/19163900/credit_irina-dmitrienko-_-alamy.jpg?crop=16:9,smart&width=1200&height=675&upscale=true" alt="za dengi da"></a>
          <div class="info">
            <a href="#">
              <p>Space</p>
            </a>
           
            <button>Visit Now</button>
          </div>
  
      </div>
       <div class="cardd">
            <a href="#"><img src="https://images.newscientist.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/19163900/credit_irina-dmitrienko-_-alamy.jpg?crop=16:9,smart&width=1200&height=675&upscale=true" alt="za dengi da"></a>
          <div class="info">
            <a href="#">
              <p>Space</p>
            </a>
            
            <button>Visit Now</button>
          </div>
  
      </div>
       <div class="cardd">
            <a href="#"><img src="https://images.newscientist.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/19163900/credit_irina-dmitrienko-_-alamy.jpg?crop=16:9,smart&width=1200&height=675&upscale=true" alt="za dengi da"></a>
          <div class="info">
            <a href="#">
              <p>Space</p>
            </a>
           
            <button>Visit Now</button>
          </div>
  
      </div>
       <div class="cardd">
            <a href="#"><img src=https://images.newscientist.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/19163900/credit_irina-dmitrienko-_-alamy.jpg?crop=16:9,smart&width=1200&height=675&upscale=true" alt="za dengi da"></a>
          <div class="info">
            <a href="#">
              <p>Space</p>
            </a>
           
            <button>Visit Now</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
   
        <div class="right-bar">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quos, sint?</p>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Asperiores incidunt corrupti quos recusandae optio sunt atque ab reiciendis obcaecati saepe. Vel sunt iusto rerum quibusdam.</p>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quos, sint?</p>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Asperiores incidunt corrupti quos recusandae optio sunt atque ab reiciendis obcaecati saepe. Vel sunt iusto rerum quibusdam.</p>
        
        </div>
    </div>

ЕЩЕ ОДИН CSS КОД 

.main-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr); 
    grid-template-rows: repeat(1);
    background-color: teal;
  }

.left-bar {
 grid-column: 1/3;
}

.ss {
 grid-column: 3/11;
}

.right-bar {
grid-column: 11/13;
}

.left-bar p, .right-bar p {
  margin: 1em;
  padding: 1em;
  padding-bottom: 1em;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0.5px;
  color: rgb(95, 9, 95);
  border-color: rgb(95, 9, 95);
}

  @media (max-width: 900px) {
   
    .main-container {
      grid-template-rows: repeat(3);
    }
    .left-bar {
      grid-column: 1/13;
      grid-row: 1/2;
    }
     
     .ss {
      grid-column: 1/13;
      grid-row: 2/3;
     }
     
     .right-bar {
     grid-column: 1/13;
      grid-row: 3/4;
    }
      }
      @media (max-width: 600px) {
       
        .main-container {
          grid-template-rows: repeat(1);
        }
        .left-bar {
          grid-column: 1/13;
          grid-row: 1/2;
         }
         
         .ss {
          grid-column: 1/11;
          grid-row: 2/3;
         }
         
         .right-bar {
         grid-column: 1/13;
         grid-row: 3/4;
         }
       

         
      }
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: только учусь,не судите строго

Comment: html добавляй тоже

Comment: ниже добавил zzz

Comment: Поле ответ только для ответов. Для добавления информации в вопрос используй кнопку [edit] под вопросом

Comment: А,хорошо.А что скажете то,как сделать посередине?